# Chrome scrolls to wrong location on anchor tags

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll, mobile-safari

While working on this locally, chrome, safari and firefox (all on OS X) all scrolled to the proper locations when using the menu at the bottom.

Now that it's being accessed online (from a windows machine), chrome doesn't scroll to the right locations, but IE does. Interestingly, mobile safari is also having the same issue.

Each link in the footer at the bottom should scroll to its corresponding 'label'. IE does that fine, but chrome just puts me 'sort of near' there.

http://www.colinandmya.com/sitetest/index.html

Any help is greatly appreciated.

** EDIT: ADDED A JSFIDDLE ** 
(i hope i did it right... thanks again for letting me know the process)

http://jsfiddle.net/prefekt/aKJ3Y/

```
$(document).ready(function() {


function filterPath(string) {
return string
  .replace(/^\//,'')  
  .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]

{3,4}$/,'')  
  .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    if ( filterPath(location.pathname) == 

filterPath(this.pathname)
&& location.hostname == this.hostname
&& this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
  var $targetId 

= $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : 

$targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
   if ($target) {
     var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;


 $(this).click(function() {
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
       return false;


 });
  }
}
  });
});
```

Comment: post the relevant code here and/or put it in a [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net).  a link to your site, while it may be helpful for us to solve the issue, won't help anyone in the future with similar issue once your site is fixed

Comment: Will do, thanks! (Sorry for being less-than-helpful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is how you are embedding the youtube video. z-index is ignored

try this script to fix

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('iframe').each(function(){
          var url = $(this).attr("src");
          var char = "?";
          if(url.indexOf("?") != -1){
                  var char = "&";
           }

          $(this).attr("src",url+char+"wmode=transparent");
    });
});
```

or just embed video in this way

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxx?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" wmode="Opaque">
```

and not in this way

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx" frameborder="0" wmode="Opaque">
```

Comment: please don't encourage a poor question by answering it.  this answer is useless to others without reference to the original code.

Comment: if you check that link in IE browser you see that the youtube video scroll over the footer.

Comment: @jason if you think a link to his site is providing original code, think again!  when the op takes faby's code and puts it in his site, the "original" code is gone.

Comment: Since the OP clearly isn't going to do it, or perhaps doesn't know how to, why don't one of you 2 answerers do the work of posting the problem code for him.  then you will have earned your rep for the answer

Comment: OP here. Apologies for not posting code the proper way. I'm still new to almost everything here and trying to learn. Since I wasn't sure what the issue was, i wasn't sure what code to post. I appreciate everyone taking the time to look at the question.

Comment: Thank you! This was it. I just added the script and everything seems to be working as it should. Thanks again.

Comment: @prefekt Remember to mark one answer as accepted to avoid your question remains unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Move the following line:

```
var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
```

To within the click event:

```
$(this).click(function() {
    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

The variable was being set outside of the click event and this the targetOffset was not a current value when clicked. For more information on this, look up Javascript variable scope.

Comment: Thanks - i tried but the effect still remains the same.